# Can WordPress handle following functionalities?

Tags: posts, comments, cms, rating, customization

Now i am planning a development of a new web site and searching for a CMS. I know WP not bad, but never tried to build a complex community information site using this engine.

Among basic requirements there are following, i would call them "community": 
 - user-panel (user profile with settings, history of activity etc)
 - users possibility to rate topics/comment/post
 - posts output according to those ratings
 - site log in/register via Facebook/Twitter account etc

Are there any popular, stabe extensions that could handle those "community" needs without deep rebuilding of engine?

*I know that all of those features can more or less be made using CMS with some extension such as Joomla, Drupal and LiveStreet, but in this project i want to exclude them.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times when someone uses the words "Wordpress" and "community" together the answer is [Buddypress](http://buddypress.org/).

Regarding your requirements I would say:

- social media login,
- user panel

can be handled well by plugins, but

- content rating,
- output content based on ratings

sounds like something that has to be custom-coded.

But this also depends on what content should be voted on and how the voting should be handled. I know there are buddypress plugins available for rating forum posts and pictures.

I would advise you to just install wordpress + buddypress and some plugins and see if this provides you with 95% or 50% of your requirements. After all it's not only about if there are plugins available for something but also how they work.